# Python Selenium navigate and click a menu voice

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i have a website made of a table. Each row has two **a** link elements.
Clicking on the second one it triggers a javascript which opens a menu.

With selenium i should navigate that menu till the "Properties" voice and to its relative submenu voice "Versions".

i tried with a simple find_element by Link_text, but it won't find the item

```
driver.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value="Properties").click()
```

i also tried with a try block but still won't find my element

```
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Properties")))
    print("Found")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Not Found!")
```

how can i access that element?
I need to select the menu voice "Properties", this way will be showed a submenu with the voice "Versions" which is the one i need to click.

How to do that?

here i attach a sample of the html code of the page

```
<td class="browseItemName" scope="rowgroup" nowrap="" width="100%">
    <a class="mylink1" href="/test/">test link</a>
    <a href="" onclick="showFunctionMenu2('rand', 7978424, event, '', '' );setSectionName('');return false"></a>
    <div class="functionMenuDiv" style="left: 359px; top: 516px; z-index: 5; visibility: visible;">
        <span class="functionMenu">
            <div
                class="menuItem"
                onclick="javascript:popup_callback( escape( '/testlink/test12' ),'');return false;"
                onmouseover="javascript:hiLight( 'mymenu0' );doSubMenu( 'mymenu0', 'funMenu4124' );"
                onmouseout="javascript:loLight( 'mymenu0' );"
                width="100%"
            >
                <a href="javascript:popup_callback( escape( '/testlink/test12' ),'');" onfocus="doSubMenu( 'mymenu0', 'funMenu4124' );">Download</a>
            </div>
            <div id="mymenu14" class="menuItem" onmouseover="javascript:hiLight( 'mymenu14' );doSubMenu( 'mymenu14', 'funMenu4124' );" width="100%">
                <div class="menuItemWithSubmenu" onclick="javascript:doKeyboardSubMenu( 'mymenu14', 'funMenu4124', event );return false;">
                    <a href="javascript:doSubMenu( 'mymenu14', 'funMenu4124' );">Properties</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="lastItemHilite"><img src="/tessst/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" /></div>
        </span>
        <span class="subMenu" id="mymenu14Sub">
            <div
                class="menuItem"
                onclick="javascript:popup_callback( escape( '/testlink/viewType%3D1' ), '' );return false;"
                onmouseover="javascript:hiLight( 'mymenu14.0' );doSubMenu( 'mymenu14.0', 'mymenu14Sub' );"
                onmouseout="javascript:loLight( 'mymenu14.0' );"
                width="100%"
            >
                <a href="/testlink/viewType%3D1">General</a>
            </div>
            <div
                class="menuItem"
                onclick="javascript:popup_callback( escape( '/testlink/3D1' ), '' );return false;"
                onmouseover="javascript:hiLight( 'mymenu14.5' );doSubMenu( 'mymenu14.5', 'mymenu14Sub' );"
                onmouseout="javascript:loLight( 'mymenu14.5' );"
                width="100%"
            >
                <a href="/testlink/func=ll&amp;objId=79">Versions</a>
            </div>
            <div class="lastItemHilite"><img src="/tessst/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" /></div>
        </span>
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"{xpath}")
```

In this case xpath would be the link's xpath. If your wondering how to get xpath then go right-click inspect the link element. Then the elements "source code" will come up on the right. Right-click that and click copy > copy full xpath.

Comment: i don't have the xpath when i right click... how else can i get it?

Comment: @antonioa7 Its quite hard to explain in words but I would recommend just giving it a google or watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSiYpmvA50A